# Within column operations in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
dt<- data.table(group= c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
var1=c("a","b","c","c","c","a"),
              var2=c(100,150,150,120,80,100))
   group var1 var2
1:     1    a  100
2:     1    b  150
3:     2    c  150
4:     2    c  120
5:     3    c   80
6:     3    a  100
```

Where the group variables indicate that observations are of the same group.

I would like to perform operations within columns.

I would like to do two things:
First is to create an indicator variable that identifies observations where var1 is the same within each group. So for instance, in the example dataset, the `IDvar1` variable would take the value of 1 for group 2 given that `var1` is the same (c) for both observations in the group.

Second, create a variable that indicates the within-group difference of `var2`. so for instance for group 1 `diffvar2` would take the value of 50, given that 150-100=1.

The final dataset should look something like this.

```
   group var1 var2 IDvar1 diffvar2
1:     1    a  100      0       50
2:     1    b  150      0       50
3:     2    c  150      1      -30
4:     2    c  120      1      -30
5:     3    c   80      0       20
6:     3    a  100      0       20
```

Any suggestions on how to do this in a clean and efficient way?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped by 'group', compare whether the number of observations (`.N`) is not equal to the number of unique observations of 'var1' (`uniqueN`) to create the 'IDvar1', and get the `diff`erence of 'var2' to create the 'diffvar2' column

```
library(data.table)
dt[, c("IDvar1", "diffvar2") := .(+(uniqueN(var1) != .N), 
       diff(var2)[1]) , by = group]
```

-output

```
> dt
   group   var1  var2 IDvar1 diffvar2
   <num> <char> <num>  <int>    <num>
1:     1      a   100      0       50
2:     1      b   150      0       50
3:     2      c   150      1      -30
4:     2      c   120      1      -30
5:     3      c    80      0       20
6:     3      a   100      0       20
```

Comment: Thanks this is great, would you mind explaining the process a little more? Why you had to put `+` in front of the `uniqueN`. Also in `diff(var2)[1]` does `[1]` indicate taking the difference with the first row?

Comment: @Alex 1) `+` coerce logical to binary (or use `as.integer`) i.e. TRUE ->1  and FALSE -> 0,  2) `diff` returns output will length 1 less than the original length of the column per group, I used `[1]` because your groups have length of 2 and wants the difference to fill up the whole column per group.  If you have more than 2 elements per group, `c(0, diff(var2))` to append 0 at the top

Comment: Great I did not know the `+` meaning! thanks for clarifying this

Answer (score 1):

@akrun has a great answer using `data.table`, I figured a `dplyr` solution might also be welcome (slower, but a bit more readable).

```
library(dplyr)
df <- as_tibble(dt)

df <- df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(
        IDvar1 = if_else(length(unique(var1)) == 1, 1, 0), # if there is only one unique value of var1 within each group, IDvar1 is 1, else it is 0
        diffvar2 = diff(var2)[1]
    )
```

In general, I would be careful with `diff()`, especially when grouping because this will instantly break if there aren't exactly two observations per group.