# Function or operation within same column / factor R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with multiple columns and multiple variables, like this one (just as example):

```
data.frame(zone = paste(rep("USA", 5), rep("EU", 5), rep("AFR", 5)),
           level = rep(c("Sea", "flatland", "hill", "mountain", "ground"),3),
           value = rnorm(15, 5, 6)
)  

  zone    level       value
1  USA EU AFR      Sea  17.5153838
2  USA EU AFR flatland   8.4582866
3  USA EU AFR     hill  -2.3369171
4  USA EU AFR mountain   9.4342822
5  USA EU AFR   ground   0.1386489
6  USA EU AFR      Sea  -4.7560599
7  USA EU AFR flatland   0.6713699
8  USA EU AFR     hill  -0.7720021
9  USA EU AFR mountain  11.5340647
10 USA EU AFR   ground  10.3560309
11 USA EU AFR      Sea   6.7660739
12 USA EU AFR flatland   6.3539702
13 USA EU AFR     hill -11.6219717
14 USA EU AFR mountain   0.8436605
15 USA EU AFR   ground   1.6643258
```

I would like to create a new column where I subtract the value of `Sea` from all the other levels in `level`.
for instance: flatland-Sea, hill-Sea, mountain-Sea and so on

Grouping by `zone`.

Consider that this is just an example. I might have more levels in `level` that I would like to operate and not necessarily the same number in each `zone`, so I am looking for a generic solution.

I tried to look at this past question (which does not ask the same thing but I tried to take inspiration only): [Within column operations in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340432/within-column-operations-in-r)
using `dplyr`, but I do not manage to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a group by and subtract by subsetting the value with a logical condition on the `level`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(zone) %>%
  mutate(Diff = value - value[level == "Sea"][1]) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   zone       level      value     Diff
   <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 USA EU AFR Sea      11.7      0     
 2 USA EU AFR flatland -2.04   -13.8   
 3 USA EU AFR hill      4.71    -7.03  
 4 USA EU AFR mountain  0.775  -11.0   
 5 USA EU AFR ground    9.08    -2.65  
 6 USA EU AFR Sea       5.78    -5.96  
 7 USA EU AFR flatland 11.7     -0.0777
 8 USA EU AFR hill     17.4      5.62  
 9 USA EU AFR mountain  5.84    -5.89  
10 USA EU AFR ground    1.79    -9.94  
11 USA EU AFR Sea       0.0589 -11.7   
12 USA EU AFR flatland  3.42    -8.31  
13 USA EU AFR hill      4.58    -7.15  
14 USA EU AFR mountain 17.0      5.21  
15 USA EU AFR ground   -1.77   -13.5
```